# Browser Game - Javascript HTML5 Saving/Storing Sensor Data with Time-stamp and uploading to Server/Database

Tags: javascript, html, upload, save, accelerometer

I'm very inexperienced with coding and would like to put forward some questions to this community.

**Background:** I'm currently working on creating a browser game using Phaser (***HTML5 and Javascript***), to be used to collect data from iPads accelerometer/gyroscope/touch-screen sensors during gameplay. I'm using Phaser guides to create game content, and have found some code that lets me see the accelerometer data (still searching for gyro) but my questions are as follows;

**Question 1:** How and what code can I implement to timestamp and save/store data that is read from the gyroscope, accelerometer, and touchscreen (at ~80Hz or as often as possible) over the duration of the browser game?

An example of what I want to get out of this is values ordered in the following fashion:

Time (ms)| Accelerometer (x, y, z) | Gyroscope (roll, pitch, yaw) | Touchscreen (X, Y)

t1 | value x1, value y1, value z1 | value r1, value p1, value y1 | value X1, value Y
t2 | value x2, value y2, value z2 | value r2, value p2, value y2 | value X2, value Y2

... continued till end of game

**Question 2:** How can I get the above example as a file sent from the iPad that I can access with my PC.

I understand memory may be an issue at high-frequency sampling and so smaller packets every so often to be appended to the main file would be ideal? but again I have no idea how to do this :S

**Question 3:** How can I save this file with a 'Username' name that can be assigned at the start of the game?

**Thank you**, and please let me know if something is confusing and I will try to clarify my question! :)

Kind regards,

Yllenus

Comment: How do you want to use the data you save? Why are thinking of something special?  If you are just starting, and you want to get gyro and accelerometer info and use it with a high frequency, you should consider going directly to java (or swift?)

Comment: _Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: Hello cauchy, I would like to use the data in Matlab to analyse parameters from the interaction (max accel at impact etc). It was recommended for me to try create this game in a browser for easier coding (since im a novice) and it makes it easier to run on other devices like an iPhone, Andriod, and avoids the apple app license difficulty :) Other than that I don't really know the pro's and con's of alternatives, let alone what alternatives there are :S

Comment: The [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=deviceorientation) resources tab may be useful. Also, check out [gyronorm](https://github.com/dorukeker/gyronorm.js) and their ebook.